# Отладка событий и выполняемых функций

Tags: отладка, javascript

Подскажите инструменты для отладки выполняемых функций в текущий момент. 
К примеру, есть большая библиотека на JS, и мне нужно  узнать есть ли листенер к событию keydown, если да, то какую функцию он вызывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chrome developer tools (тот что в гуглохром встроен)

[image: F12]